# numpy complains of libgfortran needing GCC_4.8.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

RHEL7 machine

Had created a python venv with python3.11 and installed numpy.

While trying to import numpy runs into the following error

```
bash-4.2$ env311/bin/python
Python 3.11.0 (main, Sep 12 2023, 05:24:12) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ImportError: /usr/software/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.8.0' not found (required by /u/userx/py-venv/env311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libgfortran-040039e1.so.5.0.0)
```

My gcc is at version 4.8.5

```
bash-4.2$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC)
bash-4.2$
```

Is there a way I could make the libgfortran .so run at the gcc version in the system ?
Or any other workaround ?

Tried creating the python venv with python3.10, the same error persisted.

Comment: This issue looks similar.  Are your gcc and libgcc in different places? https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10972